# How to Checkout local SVN repo using yocto recipe

Tags: svn, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have a checkout svn repository to my host machine & now I want my yocto recipe to clone the source from the localhost machine.

I know how to do this for git repo,

```
 SRC_URI = "git:///home/username/git-repo/;protocol=file;branch=master"
```

I'm doing the same for svn repo,

```
 SRC_URI = "svn:///home/username/svn-repo/;module="test";protocol=file;rev=head"
```

But it gives me the following error,

```
 svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository
 svn: E180001: Unable to open repository
```

Am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Yocto/OE fetcher of [git](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py#n24) does have the `protocol=file`.

However, this is not possible with [Subversion](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/svn.py#n68).  Anyhow, I think it's not possible at all to do this with Subversion.

But why not adding your code to a svn server and fetching it from there?  It will make it easier for other users to use the Bitbake recipe.